# Is it possible to kill Astrid without committing a crime?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

When my character killed Grelod the Kind, it was with a crouched sneak attack from behind using a conjured sword in her personal bedroom with the door closed. This did not increment any of my crimes -- assault and murder counters remained at zero. Is it possible to do the same with Astrid in the Abandoned Shack?

Since she is the corner, there is no way to get out of her line of sight. You cannot get out unless someone dies it seems, but my end goal will be to destroy the Dark Brotherhood. At the same time, it would be nice if my crime counters (other than lockpicking) were still at zero when all is said and done.

Comment: Its been a long time since i last played skyrim but? : http://i.imgur.com/BT84X.png

Comment: @MarcoGeertsma LOL. No need.

Comment: Actually, I don't think you get any bounty for killing Grelod either way. She has 1 HP for the quest, and is scripted to die that way, so hidden or not, you should be safe.

Comment: Would some fury spell work on Astrid? Or does killing people who attacked you in a rage still count as assault? Or doesn't it work on Astrid?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Stop bounty from increasing

So, in your little shack, you have the 3 captives, and Astrid.

You simply walk up to Astrid, give her a love tap (kill her), and walk right out of the shack.

The reason why it's that easy is because of the below:

- The people are blinded by their hoods, and are not classes as **"free"** NPC's. They are scripted to sit down and not move. You won't get bounty from killing Astrid if their still alive, *just* as you wouldn't if you kill any of them.
- Astrid is the ***only*** **"free"** NPC that can see you. After killing her, if you got a bounty **at all** (which you won't), it will immediately disappear as Astrid is the ***only*** witness to the crime.

I mean, who would put bounty on your head for killing the leader of the most feared group of Assassins in all of Tamriel?

---

## Stop assaults from increasing

The sad thing is, is that Assaults are as vital of a statistic as Distance Walked. They can't be erased or worked around. (I don't know much about Assaults myself) But judging on everything we have been commenting about, Assaults is more of a "This is how many people you have killed" counter.

I never look at it anyway. You **will** have to kill people sometime.

As for Astrid's situation, it's up to you. You either kill her, get 1 Assault increment, or kill 1, 2 or 3 of her captives, and get 1 Assault increment each.

As for Grelod, well, as I have stated many times, I believe she is the **one** worthless, 1 HP woman, who when you kill, has either been scripted to raise nothing (doesn't even give me a bounty when Michelle see's me kill her), or it was your lucky day and you got glitched.

Comment: I tried that, but my assault counter incremented by one. It makes sense considering that she was not an enemy when I attacked her. Are you saying that my attack has to be strong enough to kill her in one hit?

Comment: @NoctisSkytower Did you kill her? Or just tap her? Also try killing the others. Their no use anyway. :P

Comment: @NoctisSkytower Another thing you can try, is to get right into the corner of the bookcase, and just one hit her.

Comment: After punching her, my "Assaults" definitely read as "1" in the menu. If I kill after that, the count does not reduce itself back to zero. Is there something I am doing wrong?

Comment: @NoctisSkytower Hmm... Ok. Things to try: Check your crime menu and check for **active** bounties, and then try killing the hostages too.

Comment: @NoctisSkytower And are you talking about crime when you say Assaults? As in, 1500 **crime** for killing a civilian.

Comment: No, when you press the "Esc" key, click on "General Stats," point at "CRIME," and then scan through the list of crime types on the right, there is a crime type of "Assaults." This has nothing to do with bounty.

Comment: @NoctisSkytower Ah. Well assault basically means that you have **murdered** someone in cold blood! No crime though. Crime is only calculated via. bounty.

Comment: @NoctisSkytower As for Grelod. I have no idea. She is scripted to die with a one hit shot on her too, and is ***also*** scripted to not increase bounty, so I'm assuming it goes the same for her assault.

Comment: My definition of a crime is anything that increments the counters in the crime section of the general stats (other than lockpicking). According to [Skyrim:Crime](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Crime), `Assault. Starting a fight with a non-hostile NPC (except a brawl).` I was able to kill Grelod the Kind without getting the **Assults** counter to increment. Is the same possible with Astrid?

Comment: @NoctisSkytower Assuming you read my Grelod comment, I am going to have an educated guess and say **you can't** get away with it for Astrid. (Unless maybe you one hit her). As for your question itself, I based my answer off of the **Bounty** aspect of **Crime**.

Comment: Thank you! I will have to experiment with a super-weapon to see if it is possible then.

Comment: @NoctisSkytower LOL. Time to pull out the BFG.

Comment: @NoctisSkytower Or maybe... Some (*cough* obviously not OP *cough*) Fortify Restoration weapons? :P

Comment: Well, I killed her with a legendary ebony sword doing 4096 damage (one hit kill). **Assaults** still went up by one. My guess is that either my character must never sleep or must be able to justify assaulting the leader of a murderous organization. The later sounds like a better option.

Comment: @NoctisSkytower Well then... I don't know what to say... Im going to assume that attacking ***anyone*** except for certain scripted NPC's, causes Assault to go up then...

Comment: There's a difference between bounties and crimes. You can avoid bounties for crimes you commit but you can never avoid the game counting the crime in the statistics page. If you care about the statistics page the only solution is to not commit the crime.  Assault outside of self-defense is always a crime. You can avoid the bounty but not the counter. The same thing is true for theft - you can steal without getting caught in game and avoid bounties, but the statistics page still tracks your stolen item count.

Comment: @jw013 There we go! And to top that off, if you get thrown into the Abandoned shack, your counter **WILL** increase no matter what. (without hacks of course) because someone **HAS** to die.

Comment: @jw013 I have added the Assault aspect to the answer.

Answer (score -1):

You don't because the other people are blindfolded with masks so astrid is the only npc that can see you and you carnt get a bounty from someone who is dead - Bethsdea made it realistic if you know what I mean.